# custom redirection inside the authorize() function in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Trying to make a redirect with the value of specific input data once the validation fails.

```
  public function authorize() {
   $data = $this->all();
   return redirect()->back()->with('cat_id',$data['category_id']);
  }
```

```
public function rules()
    {
        if($this->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            return [
             'category_id' => 'required',
            ];

        } 
    }
```

What I want is to redirect the request back with `category_id` input value. Looked at documentation of laravel but couldn't find the way.

Tried : `$this->input('category_id')` , `request()->category_id`, `$this->route()->parameter('category_id')`, `$this->get("category_id")`

None of them above used to work unfortunately.Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the redirect back is going to have all the inputs already by default with how FormRequests work .... are you just trying to rename that input?  also the `authorize` method is for authorizing, not sure what you are trying to do with it

Comment: I need the value of `category_id` and send it back within `redirect()` function. As I am using extended `Request` form I am unable to use `redirect()` in my controller file. I am not stick only on `authorize()` function but inside of this anywhere would be fine.

Comment: at least if I would be able to ignore the `redirect` function which works inside of the custom validation and make it work from controller level that also would solve my issue.

Comment: `request()->session()->get('cat_id')`

Comment: I beleive you suggest the line like this: `return redirect()->back()->with('cat_id', request()->session()->get('cat_id'));` which I did know but no, doesn't work can't get value.